# Why does Unix store timestamps in a signed integer?

Tags: timestamps

Why is a signed integer used to represent timestamps? There is a clearly defined start at 1970 that's represented as 0, so why would we need numbers before that? Are negative timestamps used anywhere?

Comment: That's why Nostradamus couldn't use his computer to write his predictions for the years 3000+... it would cause an overflow and show his dates as negative.  I think they called it the Y3K bug or something!

Comment: The ancient Romans had an even worse problem when year numbers switched from negative to positive.  They would have called it the Y0K problem if they'd had a way to express the number zero.  8-)}

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Early versions of C didn't have unsigned integers.  (Some programmers used pointers when they needed unsigned arithmetic.)  I don't know which came first, the `time()` function or unsigned types, but I suspect the representation was established before unsigned types were universally available.  And 2038 was far enough in the future that it probably wasn't worth worrying about.  I doubt that many people thought Unix would still exist by then.

Another advantage of a signed `time_t` is that extending it to 64 bits (which is already happening on some systems) lets you represent times several hundred billion years into the future without losing the ability to represent times before 1970.  (That's why I oppose switching to a 32-bit *unsigned* `time_t`; we have enough time to transition to 64 bits.)

Comment: The `time` function is older than the epoch: [Unix v1](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/2/sys-time) (in 1971) counted in units of 1/60th of a second, from midnight on 1971/01/01. It was already a [known bug that “The chronological--minded user will note that 2**32 sixtieths of asecond is only about 2.5 years.”](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/time) `unsigned` was introduced by [K&R in 1978](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C), well after the 1970 epoch was established.

Comment: I did a quick test and on my 64-bit linux box. `gmtime` and `localtime` max out in the year 2147483647 (with the next second after giving -2147483648 as the year). So to get much past 55 bits of time somebody will have to update the output routine to use a 64-bit int for the year instead of an unsigned 32-bit int. Hopefully somebody will take care of that bug sometime in the next couple billion years.

Comment: @freiheit: Interesting.  The problem there is that the `struct tm` type has a member `tm_year` (representing years since 1900) which is of type `int`.  64-bit systems can easily have a 64-bit `time_t`, but they typically have a 32-bit `int`.  (If `char` is 8 bits and `int` is 64 bits, then `short` can be either 16 or 32 bits, and there will be no predefined type for the other size.)  But `time()` is probably the only function in `<time.h>` that really requires system-level support; you can write your own code to convert `time_t` values to human-readable strings.

Answer (score 19):

It's to support timestamps and dates before January 1st, 1970.

Comment: This makes only 68 years in the past - 1902. This seems quite a little.

Comment: POSIX doesn't require `time_t` to be only 32 bits; it's already 64 bits on many systems.

Comment: `mktime()` function returns `-1` in case of error so it's probably impossible to distinguish between correct timestamps before 1970-01-01 and error ts. Apparenlty dates before 1970-01-01 are prohibited

Comment: @DimG: It's difficult to distinguish between an error and the specific timestamp `1969-12-31 23:59:59 UTC`. A negative value other than `-1` is unambiguous.

Comment: @KeithThompson that breaks the whole idea, no?

Comment: @DimG: How so? It is mildly unfortunate that `mktime()` uses in-band error signalling, but it only means that one particular moment, unlikely to appear in practice, cannot be easily distinguished from an error. With that one exception, `mktime()` works just fine for times before and after the epoch. If I were designing the interface today, I'd probably either use some other mechanism to indicate an error, or use a defined constant with an implementation-defined value rather than `-1`.

Comment: @DimG Set `errno = 0` right before calling `mktime` and check the value of `errno` immediately after before calling any other library function. That's your actual error indicator, don't think of the `-1` as indicating error, think of it as just being a garbage value because in the event of error the return value has to still contain something.

Comment: @KeithThompson See my above comment re: `errno` for out-of-band error indication on `mktime`.

Comment: @mtraceur: The C standard doesn't require a failing `mktime()` call to set `errno`. (POSIX does.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for pointing that out. I neglected to do due diligence and double-check C's spec before commenting.